# CSS Selecting element after chosen class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm modifying JQuery UI Accordion Menu, which currently has a structure as below:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<div>Children</div>
<h3 class="no-children">Title</h3>
<div>Children</div>
<h3>Title</h3>
<div>Children</div> ...
```

As you can see, the middle title has no children, so what I want to do in CSS is something along the lines of selecting the div that occurs after the .no-children class and hide it. These are not nested so I can't do this the easy way.

I know I can `display:none` but I can't seem to select the correct element.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.nochildren+div{
  /* Style goes here */
}
```

This selects a DIV that that is immediately preceded by a element with the the `.nochildren` class. This will only work if both elements are on the same level, many older browsers will have issues with it.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery there is an easy way of doing this  [Here](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: If someone is doing jquery UI accordion, I think the odds of him using jquery are Reeally high.

Comment: I am using jQuery... obviously... but I was kinda hoping to do this through pure CSS, because I'm using a CMS and I was trying to just override the JQuery UI styles in my own theme.

Comment: Ah, apologies, didn't notice the sentence at the top

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$('.no-children').next().hide();
```

or `.nextUntil();`

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/DqpPd/1/

---

CSS way would be

```
.no-children + div { display: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/DqpPd/ ( ie7+ )